# Embedded jetty 9 doesn't work for @Webservlet

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I'm using java 11 and embedded jetty 9 foor my javaEE application,I'm trying to use @Websevlet annotation to publish my servlet but it doesn't work i don't know why.
My start class java

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;

import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.*;

public class Start  {

    public static  void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(80);

        WebAppContext wacHandler = new WebAppContext();
        wacHandler.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]
                {
                        new AnnotationConfiguration(),
                        new WebInfConfiguration(),
                        new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                        new MetaInfConfiguration(),
                        new FragmentConfiguration(),
                        new JettyWebXmlConfiguration()
                });
        server.setHandler(wacHandler);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

My hello world class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet( "/getservlet")
public class ServletX extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
      
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>Hi there..</h1>");
    }

}
```

I don't have a web.xml configuration ,Should i do?

Comment: Where is the ServletX?  Is it in a WAR file that the embedded Jetty is using?  or is it somewhere else, like in a uberjar, or the container classpath?

Comment: the servletX in the WAR file that embedded jetty use

Comment: Then why have you not referenced that WAR file in your example code?  The `WebAppContext` should have a `setWar()` or `.setBaseResource()` called against the WAR (or unpacked webapp directory) for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ServletX` is in the war file, meaning it's in `WEB-INF/classes/` archive directory, then the configuration you have declared (specifically the `AnnotationConfiguration`) will perform a bytecode scan of the WAR file and load the `@WebServlet` annotation.

Also note that the `WebAppContext` will need point to this WAR file, which your code examples do not do.

```java
WebAppContext wacHandler = new WebAppContext();
waxHandler.setWar("/path/to/myapp.war");
// ... more setup
```

But! if the `ServletX` is not in the WAR file, but is instead housed with your embedded-jetty `Start` class, then you'll need to expose the servlet container to be scanned by the bytecode scanning step.

You can always turn on DEBUG/FINE level logging for the named logger `org.eclipse.jetty` and see the activity being performed with regards to the deployment and bytecode scanning.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help i have the second case may servletX in my embedded-jetty start class can you give more details about this case.